# How can I replace the eighteenth character before space character (without match this only match the space character )?

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I have a string

```
"onetwomappleapplejackfire computer stringspaceredpineapple roughapplepainregex"
```

I want to find the eighteenth character before the space.

I have a similar command to find the eighteenth character *after* a space:

```
\s(?=.{18}(.))
```

replace with this $1

I want to do this, but in reverse.

also im triying lookbehind but not work

```
   (?<=(.).{18})\s
```

also

```
     (?=(.).{18})\s
```

I cant capture a group $1

I want the command not stop after first match

also
i want the command find all spaces  in text (not skipping space )

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex : `(?<=([\w\s])[\w\s]{17})\s`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/oL6hM2/5)

Comment: hi i want substitute by $1 and get the 18th character after replace

Comment: and not to stop at the first search

Comment: im triying to look behind but not work for me (?<=(.).{18})\s

Comment: Actually it should work for other characters also. Edited.

Comment: i cant capture a lookbehind group and replace

Comment: The regex I used is lookbehind. Do you mean notepad++ is not finding group ?

Comment: but in your example not see the substitution

Comment: ([\w\s]) gives the group you want, but I see your problem now, notepad++ is not finding the group either with \1 or $1

Comment: but the problem is elditor or command ,
your example is nothing like the command I put in my example

Comment: another problem when i triying use your command this stop after first match

Comment: did you see the link in the demo?

Comment: yes i see , I do this example to search earlier words and add

Comment: i want replace only the spaces without stop at the first match

Comment: i see this "onetwomappleapplejackfirecomputerstringspaceredpineapple"
"onetwom_ppleapplsjackfirecomputerstringspaceredpineapple"

Comment: i see a think you command is correct, but  I do not know why it does not work in notepad ++
I'll wait 1 day and if no one answers me,  I accept you response thanks for all

Comment: probably is a bug in Notepad ++

Comment: very thank you for all ,i try this command in regex101 and also work (?<=(.).{18})\s